# what type of token is this (similar to JWT)?

Tags: jwt, token

```
{"typ":"MT","alg":"RS256"}
```

Mostly i have seen typ:JWT, DO anyone knows what token is this?

Comment: some proprietary system? in which context you have founded it?

Comment: I recently came across a JWT issued by DocuSign with the header: `{ "typ": "MT", "alg": "RS256", "kid": "<uuid>" }`. I'm also curious what the MT means. The payload seems to be binary but has the `kid` uuid inside it twice.

Comment: Hey Corey, Yes it is from that only. And still after a year i am not able to find the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

I`m not sure but could "MT" stand for "machine translation"? Make this sense for your context?
Do you use machine-to-machine communication?
Regards